# How change I make sure that jQuery will only execute this code when the slider is visible?

Tags: jquery, slider

OK I'm almost finished doing my website at http://www.gablabelle.com/ but I have a small problem.

I use a slider to showcase my photos and when you click on one of the thumbnails the slider div fadeIn. When you change slide using the arrows, right/left keyboard keys, mouse click or by swiping, the URL will change accordingly to reflect the slide it's on, thanks to jQuery address plugin. Pressing ESC or the logo will fadeOut the slider div.

The problem is that when I load the homepage, but do not click on any thumbnail and press the right and left keyboard keys the URL changes (because it's actually changing the slides of the slider even if you can't see it).

The slide changes don't bother because when I click on a thumbnail the right slide comes in anyway. This is the piece of code that makes the URL change when the slide is changed:

```
slider.ev.on('rsAfterSlideChange', function(event) {
    $.address.state(ajax_object.path).crawlable(true).value(slider.currSlide.caption);
});
```

How change I make sure that jQuery will only execute this code when the slider is visible?

Many thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `if ($(slider).is(":visible")) { // execute operation }`, replace the sliderselector with the correct selector for your slider.  `$(this).is(":visible")` may also work.

Comment: "(" missing in your answer. @GAB. In your code is the same error! Try: "if($(slider).is(":visible")) {...}"

Comment: A better alternate is to work with jQuery "promises". Check http://api.jquery.com/promise/